# How to inspect any mobile applications design css on anoriod phone

Tags: android, css, ios

My job as a designer requires me to check CSS or examine mobile applications, for instance **Amazon's app**, to find out how **big the cards are (height and width), what fonts they use, margins,** etc. ***on my mobile phone, not on the web browser***, so is there any application or feature I can use to check an application's elements?

Answer (score 0):

Read these articles. The may help:

[INSPECTING MOBILE APPLICATIONS — RIGHT WAY](https://medium.com/@edmond.dantes/inspecting-mobile-applications-right-way-55534d569c85)

[How to Inspect Element on Android Device](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-inspect-element-on-android)